# //TODO flag in VS .Net

Tags: visual-studio

In eclipse, if you write a comment such as `//TODO something-or-other`, you are able to track and navigate back to all of your TODOs via a Task Pane.  Is there any similar device in VS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Menu => View => Task List
In the combo box select "Comments"

Comment: The comments keywords being used to build the task list can actually be configured via Tools->Options->Environment->Task List

Answer (score 3):

```
//todo: whatever
//TODO: work on blah blah
//Todo new screenshot
```

All work (at least in 2008 and probably previous versions as well).

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, click on the View menu then Task List. Use the drop down on the upper left corner of the Task List to view "Comments".

Bonus info: HACK and UNDONE are also keywords that show up in the list.

To add your own custom keywords, view the Tools->Options menu, selected Environment node, then Task List node.

Answer (score 0):

TODO will work.  [Here is a link](http://dotnetperls.com/todo-comments-visual-studio)

Comment: 10. Track things you have to do with Task List
The Task List window (Ctrl+Alt+K) allows you to keep track of the things you have to do. Right click on the Task List window and choose Show Tasks|All to see a list of tasks. Ctrl+Shift+F12 to cycle through your list of tasks.

By default, comments marked with a TODO will appear in the task list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's also

```
//TODO: My task
```

You can look up what tasks you have todo'd by looking at the "Task List"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

- Click on View -> Other Windows -> Task List (occasionally it's directly under View)
- Switch the ComboBox to Comments

This will now display all TODO comments found in your code base that appear inside comments.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Check out [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/06/16/you-can-do-the-todos-today-too.aspx):

> While working on a file, you can open the task list window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>,
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), open that drop-down menu and choose “Comments”.

Comment: @iosDev82 I agree. Edited :)